# $a_k$ is a countable sequence of positive numbers st. $\gcd(a_1,a_2,...)=1$, show exists a finite subsequence $a_{i_1},a_{i_2},...,a_{i_n}$ with gcd 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

The question is,

> Let $a_k$ be a countably infinite sequence of positive numbers st. $\gcd(a_1,a_2,...)=1$, does it exist a finite subsequence $a_{i_1},a_{i_2},...,a_{i_n}$ with $\gcd(a_{i_1},a_{i_2},...,a_{i_n})=1$?

or more generally,

> Let $a_k$ be a countably infinite sequence of positive numbers st. $\gcd(a_1,a_2,...)=d$, does it exist a finite subsequence $a_{i_1},a_{i_2},...,a_{i_n}$ with $\gcd(a_{i_1},a_{i_2},...,a_{i_n})=d$?

Can anyone help with an elementary proof (pls. do not use advanced number theory stuff) or a counter example? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is  a bit of a pedestrian argument, but you asked for one:

Recall that the GCD is $1$ if and only if no prime number divides all $a_i$. 
The number $a_1$ is divisible by a finite number of primes $p_1, \dots , p_k$.  For each $p_j$ there exists some $a_{i_j}$ such that $p_j \nmid a_{i_j} $.

Now note that there is no prime number that divides each of $a_1, a_{i_1}, \dots , a_{i_k}$, and conclude.

(Note that the $a_{i_j}$ are not necessarily distinct.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $d_n=\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. Then since $\{d_n\}$ is a non-empty set of positive integers, it must have a least element.

Comment: How do you know this least element will be the gcd of all $a_i$?

Comment: That's why it is a hint. @quid

Comment: This is the main part to show though. And it might be misleading as it sugests the false argument to just assume this.

Comment: Well, yes and no. I think the "least value" is a big part of the "trick." Also, restricting it to just the case $a_1,\dots,a_n$ rather than arbitrary subsets, makes it easier to write :) @quid

Comment: Of course I thought about it. I wondered what I could give that would not give away the whole answer. I wrote the word "hint." What makes you think I wasn't aware this was not a complete proof? I actually wondered if it was too big a hint. @quid

Comment: That in my opinion the hint is "poisoned" as it is misleading, as explained.

Comment: Perhaps you just don't realize how trivial the rest of the proof is from this start? @quid

Comment: For the third time, the problem is that I believe that the way this written can mislead one to believe that the argument with the details filled in is complete and/or hint at a wrong completion of the argument. Whether or not *I* know that one can add  the min  divide all further $a_i$ and thus the gcd is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, what do I know about helping people, anyway? @quid

Comment: I will not continue this conversation at this level. Possibly I should not have shared what I am idly wondering. Sorry for this. But I am still convinced this is a risky answer in that it can very easily be misunderstood and mislead.

Comment: Just to be clear, you started the incivility when you suggested that I was being dishonest in defending my answer, and then calling my answer "poisoned." I honestly don't get your complaint, except for the possibility that you didn't know how to proceed.  @quid

Comment: I deleted that one comment  (for which I already apologized) and the poisoned was under quotes, meant to express "fairly likely to lead to a false completion"  and as explained this is the "complaint" though it is more a concern than a complaint.

Comment: I might have gone a little further and pointed out that $\langle d_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a non-increasing sequence of positive integers, but even as it stands it’s a very nice hint.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that be even more risky in that it still more directly suggests that this sequence being eventually constant at the minimum shows the claim directly.

Comment: @quid: Piffle. (And with respect to an earlier comment of yours, if the details are filled in, then the argument is **by definition** complete: the details obviously include the conclusion of the argument.)